# Interrupt or interrupting in the following context?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

Which of the following forms of verb is correct in the following context?

> "When you slept yesterday, I tiptoed to the kitchen in order to not
>   **interrupt / interrupting** you."

It'll be very helpful if you suggest a rule of thumb to solve by myself such dilemmas in future.

Comment: Are you perhaps being distracted by the syntactically irrelevant ***in order*** and/or negating ***not***? The basic construction is the same as, for example, ***I work to earn money*** and ***I went to help***. Is it not obvious to you that ***I work to earning money*** and ***I went to helping*** are badly-formed sentences?

Comment: I think I got you. You basically say that the preposition "to" in this case functions as a component of infinitive such as  **to eat**, **to go**, **to drink**, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The "to" is part of the infinitive "to interrupt," so "interrupting" is incorrect.  Extreme grammar pedants would dislike even the "to not interrupt" version for being a *split infinitive* and insist on something like:

> When you slept yesterday, I tiptoed to the kitchen in order **not to interrupt** you.

However, most modern grammarians don't really recognize the no-split-infinitive rule as valid since it's frequently violated in idiomatic spoken (and even written) English and was imposed artificially by scholars who wanted to insist that a two-word grammatical unit could not be interrupted.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought about another possible version "When you slept yesterday, I tiptoed to the kitchen in order not interrupting you.". What do you think about this version (using gerund instead of "to+infinitive")?

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work - you always have to use the phrase [in order to](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/linking-words-and-expressions/in-order-to) with an infinitive.  That's just how this idiom is constructed.