# What's the terminological name for the infinitive combination with "to" (infinitive + "to")

Tags: terminology

What's the terminological name for the **infinitive** combination with "**to**" *(infinitive + "to")*

For example: to go, to sit, to say, to speak, to drink, to eat etc. 
This kind of combination is normally located after "want", or "go", think, etc. (For instance "I want to eat.")

Comment: "Want" is a catenative verb, so this is a catenative construction where the _to_-infintival clause "to eat" is catenative complement of the verb "want".

Comment: The two-word combination ***to [verb]*** is normally just called "the infinitive". Without ***to***, it's called an ["unmarked infinitive"](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=QmJV3_MytJMC&pg=PT127&lpg=PT127&dq=define+%22unmarked+infinitive%22&source=bl&ots=4bbbDEg_JM&sig=5fy6-VQYNAIt5-UVAmKVY2NI6yw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjV34yz1sXfAhVszoUKHd8IAiAQ6AEwB3oECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=define%20%22unmarked%20infinitive%22&f=false) *(An unmarked infinitive is a **to–verb** without the **to**...).*

Comment: ...unless I'm missing something, it's archaic / dialectal to use an infinitive (marked or unmarked) after ***think***. For example, *He thinks to marry her* isn't exactly "grammatical" to the modern ear, but it probably was in Shakespeare's time.

Comment: The terms are _'to_-infinitive' and 'bare infinitive'.

Comment: btw, Witty loquacity, with reference to [Interrupt or interrupting in the following context?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/191218/interrupt-or-interrupting-in-the-following-context?noredirect=1#comment375498_191218) (against which I can't post this comment), I don't think it's necessarily helpful to delete validly-posed questions on ELU. Since the issue was sufficiently perplexing to justify you asking about it in the first place, it's quite possible *future* visitors might benefit from it (with a proper "Answer", not just my comment asking for clarification).

Comment: So I'll open it again.

Comment: As @BillJ has pointed out, the terms are "_to_-infinitive" with _to_, and "bare infinitive" without. The _to_ is called the "_to_-complementizer", or simply the "complementizer". However, the full complementizer is _for...to_, with _for_ unmarking the subject NP and _to_ marking the VP of the infinitive clause. Since the subject of an infinitive is often deleted or indefinite, the _for_ part is usually missing; it's only required when beginning a sentence: _For me to leave now would be a bad idea_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up the comments and to make them an answer. There are more that one term for "to + infinitive"  as the following:

- It's called **infinitive** (while the infinity without 'to' is called "[unmarked infinitive](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=QmJV3_MytJMC&pg=PT127&lpg=PT127&dq=define%20%22unmarked%20infinitive%22&source=bl&ots=4bbbDEg_JM&sig=5fy6-VQYNAIt5-UVAmKVY2NI6yw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjV34yz1sXfAhVszoUKHd8IAiAQ6AEwB3oECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=define%20%22unmarked%20infinitive%22&f=false)". ) - (@FumbleFingers in comments)
- '**to-infinitive**' (while "to + infinitive) and '**bare infinitive**' (infinitive without 'to'). (@BillJ in comments)

The '**to**' component of the 'to-infinitive' is called "**to-complementizer**" or simply "**complementizer**" (@John Lawler in comments)